# Connecting to SQL Server running on Parallels on Mac

Tags: sql-server, macos, parallels

I am running MAC with parallels installed.  I have windows 7 Pro installed on Parallels, and SQLServer Express 2012 installed on Windows 7.

I am trying to connect to the SQL Server database from the Mac OS, but not having any luck.

I followed [this post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012), but still unable to connect.  So I am thinking it may have to do with it running in a VM?

I'm receiving the following error when attempting to connect:

```
ERROR: An error occurred while trying to make a connection to
the database: 

JDBC URL: jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://10.211.55.4:1433;appName=RazorSQL;ssl=request;useCursors=true

Login
timed
out.
```

I am able to ping the IP address.

Has anyone set this up?  Any tricks or pointers you can suggest?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out to be the firewall on Windows 7.  Once I created a rule to allow traffic through on Port 1433, I was able to connect fine.

This was done by

1. opening "Windows Firewall with Advance Security".
2. Selecting "Inbound Rules" > "New Rule".
3. Selecting "Port" as the rule type, then entering 1433 as the port number to allow.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the default behavior of Parallels to use NAT, and use a dedicated IP (in the 10.x.x.x range to avoid IP collision with your own network!), then connect to this IP.

Comment: Thanks Parallelis.  Are you able to elaborate?  I've been poking around trying to find out how to do what you suggest, but it looks like NAT is the default. From what I can tell, "Shared Networking" is NAT, which is the setting I currently have.