# ADT and jdts - Configuring with SQL Server 2012

Tags: eclipse, sql-server-2012, adt, jtds

I'm trying to get the ADT bundle (Eclipse) to connect to an SQL-Server 2012 database.

This is what I'm trying through SQL Explorer:

[image]

And I am getting this error:

[image]

I have a user called 'admin' with a password (which I'm supplying correctly to jtds).

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your SQL-Server is not configured to allow remote connections.

Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278115/1430055

Also check for the right [authentication mode](http://www.hosting.com/support/windows-vps/remotesqlexp).