# Cannot connect to remote SQL Database with SQL Server Management Console (Error 53)

Tags: sql-server

I have opened up port 1433 on my firewall, but every time I try and connect to my remote SQL Database with SQL Server Management Console I receive (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

Comment: is tcp/ip enabled in the db? it may be using named pipes only (or some other local-only con method).

Comment: Would I have to contact my SQL Database provider to determine that?

Comment: Where is your database hosted?

Comment: yes, and also make sure you're getting mssms to use tcp/ip as well. the other connection methods are NOT routeable/useable over remote network links.

Comment: I am able to connect ok on my PC, but I receive Error 53 when trying to connect behind ISA 2004 on my SBS 2003 Server.

Comment: mind providing some more details? is the database on your network? does that server have a firewall you haven't configured? Is there a named instance?  Can you connect locally on the server?  Are you using SSMS as in these screen shots: http://www.serverintellect.com/support/sqlserver/connect-database-ssmse.aspx ?

Comment: The database is not on my server is being hosted elsewhere.  I have enabled port 1433 on my firewall.

Comment: Like I said.  If I connect at home on my PC its fine, but when I try from my SBS Server through ISA 2004 I receive error 53

Comment: Looks like you have to publish a SQL server to an ISA: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc302623.aspx

Comment: Once again, the SQL server I'm connecting to is at a remote location.  I'm not hosting it

Answer (score 15):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

[Enable remote connections for SQL Server Express 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)

**Short Answer**

- Check Firewall
- Check Service is Running
- Check TCP/IP is Enabled
- Check SQL Server Properties "Allow Remote Connections"
- Check if the SQL Server is on a restricted subnet

Then Run these if Those Do not Resolve

- Right-click on TCP/IP and select Properties.
- Verify that, under IP2, the IP Address is set to the computer's IP address on the local subnet.
- Scroll down to IPAll.
- Make sure that TCP Dynamic Ports is blank.
- Make sure that TCP Port is set to 1433.
- If you have a named instance then you must have the SQL Server Browser Service enabled
- The browser service runs on port UDP 1434 and this must be allowed through your firewall

Hail Mary Pass if this is Still not Resolved

- Go to the client machine, and run cliconfg.exe If named pipes is listed first, demote it, and promote TCP/IP.
- check if the firewall is blocking the named pipes port, which usually is 445

Comment: Another hail mary is to go into sql server configuration manager, go to the sql server protocols, and then disable tcp/ip, restart the sql service, enable tcp/ip and restart the service one more time. This has been my solution on many occasions.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is go into SQL Server Configuration Manager where SQL Server is installed.

In the Start Menu, under the Microsoft SQL Server folder, open the Configuration Tools folder and select SQL Server Configuration Manager.

In the Config Manager, click the arrow next to SQL Server Network Configuration, then click on "Protocols for {Instance}". {Instance} will be your install, if it's the default instance it will be MSSQLSERVER.

On the right side, make sure that TCP/IP is "Enabled". Double click TCP/IP, in the window that opens, change the drop down to "Yes".

Comment: Error 53 looks like a problem with the name resolution. Can you ping the server with SQL from the machine you're trying to connect to? Is it the same machine?

Comment: Yes I can ping, and it is not the same machine that I am pinging from

Comment: Here is a blog post that is related to error 53: [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sql_protocols/archive/2007/05/16/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error-xxx.aspx). It mentions using a "/" instead of a "\", unable to find the machine, and a firewall blocking the connection. Have you double checked the connection string? Is there a firewall on the machine you're connecting FROM blocking the connection?

Comment: I tried to connect using TCP/IP and I will get Error 10065 instead.

Comment: I must mention that I am using Remote Desktop to connect to my SBS server.  Would that cause problems?

Comment: Using Remote Desktop shouldn't be an issue. How are you trying to connect to SQL Server? I assumed you were using SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS), is that accurate?

Comment: Yes.  Weird thing is if I use a client computer hosted by the same SBS server I am trying to connect with, it works!  But I I try directly from the SBS server it does not.

Comment: Have you checked for a local firewall on the SBS server that would block the connection (outgoing or incoming)?

Comment: I opened port 1433 on ISA 2004.  However, this is the error I get: "Status: A packet generated on the local host was rejected because its source IP address is assigned to one network adapter and its destination IP address is reachable through another network adapter."

Comment: Please note however that if I connect via a client computer which is still going through the same SBS Server, I do not receive that ISA error.  Very strange!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is the how to fix it and gain your connectivity back:

Click WindowsKey + R and enter services.msc
Once Services opens scroll down and locate service SQL Server
Highlight the service and click START
Wait for the service to start and retry to connect to your MSSQL instance
It should now work again and you will be able to connect to your MSSQL instance and run queries.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.  Please refer to this thread: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/forefront/en-US/d2624655-e6ff-4947-b1a8-a2edcffd8a21/denied-connection-netbios-session-protocol#68321990-4ac4-46fa-b7f8-9e0ded3234bb

In detail: I was receiving the following error from ISA when trying to connect from my SBS 2003 Server to my offsite MSSQL Database Provider via SQL Server Management Studio:

Denied Connection
Log type: Firewall service
Status: A packet generated on the local host was rejected because its source IP address is assigned to one network adapter and its destination IP address is reachable through another network adapter.
Rule:
Source: Local Host ( 192.168.1.1:29859)
Destination: External (***.***.***.***:139)
Protocol: NetBios Session

I have figured this out.  I had to add "Local Host" as one of the sources for the ISA Rule that I had initially created to allow SQL Server Management Console connections in the first place.  That rule was allowing "Internal" sources but not the Local Host (127.0.01), which is needed for this scenario.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to provide the information here, and include the link as a reference for additional information. Posts that include only a link to somewhere else are not acceptable answers here, even to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

in SSMS while opening give the server name as your_Hostname\your_sqlservername (give both the names as applicable instead of local or just only servername) it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I could ping my Virtual Machine SQL server but couldn't connect to it.
I disabled my wired and wireless NICs and then it connected !