# Microsoft sql server 2008 Error: 53?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I just installed sql server 2008 . When I tried to connect it . It was showing this message :

### *TITLE: Connect to Server

Cannot connect to SQLServer.

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 53)

For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53&LinkId=20476

---

I visited the link but I didn't find any solution .

Comment: check out this link for your solution

 http://stackoverflow.com/a/21492452

Comment: Thanks . I'm trying it.

Comment: I Follow the solution & find nothing in SQL Server Services .See the screenshot: 
http://prntscr.com/6fdsyx

Comment: You quite possibly only installed the client tools. Is there anything in `services.msc`?

Comment: there is already question like this
check this out
http://stackoverflow.com/a/21492452/5277639

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something went wrong when you install it because my configuration manager show like this check snapshot here http://prntscr.com/6fdvog

Comment: I have no idea . Everything installed successfully .