# Cannot connect to SQL Server named instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sockets, tcp

I cannot connect to a named instance of SQL Server. I am trying to connect to `domain\named_instance` but **this happens to all servers I try to connect to apart from localhost**

The error that I cam getting looks like this: 
[image: After about 30 seconds of trying to connect this message displays]

So far I have tried:

1. Enabling remote connections in SQL Server
2. Enabling TCP/IP in the SQL Server Configuration Manager
3. Changing all the TCP ports in SQL Server Configuration Manager to 1433

I also tried running the command below where the number is the Process ID of the SQL Server Service:

```
 netstat -ano | find /i “7608”
```

My result was as follows:
[image]

As suggested by [this](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/) website.

However I do not get the `ESTABLISHED` return only the 2 `LISTENING` ones.
My IP2 IP address is set to: `192.168.2.176`not 100% sure if this is right or not.

I cannot (due to security issues with my hosting company) get the IP of the server. Any and all suggestions are welcome!

I am in dire straits, and really need help!

I am using SQL Server 2008

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16445243/cannot-connect-to-remote-sql-database-with-sql-server-management-console-error)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have looked at that post... Tried all of the answers mentioned by e-zero and still have the same problem.

Comment: [This might help](http://www.microsoft.com/products/ee/transform.aspx?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=53)

Comment: I'd refrain from posting information about your domain or IP addresses on the web.  Unless you want to get hacked, and since it appears you're doing work for a health care company, I'm guessing you don't want that.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion, I have tried that but it seems it was already set to allow remote connections. If you have any more suggestions please let me know! @dave luckily this is only a staging server, but I have changed it, thank you!

Comment: Check firewall restrictions on your comp.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are stating you are trying to use named pipes (can be seen in the screenshots) I think you errornously trying to use TCP configuration to do this.

You need to need to enabled SQL to listen named pipes. How to do - see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189321.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple types of error "Cannot connect to 'Server Name'".

These error are differentiated on the basis of Error Additional Information.

One of the Solution for above error is

1. Connect the server using Windows Authentication.
2. Right Click on the Server(i.e. first option) in Object Explorer. Then go to Properties.
3. Go to Security then select Server Authentication as "SQL Server and Windows Authentication Mode"
4. Again Right Click on the Server(i.e. first option) in Object Explorer. Then select restart.

Then try again login using SQL Authentication