# Connect to SQL Server via USB using VB.NET

Tags: sql, vb.net, usb

I write an application for a **Windows CE 5** device with **VB.NET**. It has installed **.NET CF 3.5**, **SQL Client 2.0** and **SQLServerCompact 3.5 Core**.

I wrote the application and now I have to connect to the SQL Server 2012 Express on my computer. The device is connected via USB to the laptop and I use **Visual Studio 2008 Professional** to run the programm on the device.

---

Here is what I have written:

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Dim conn As SqlConnection = Nothing
conn = New SqlConnection("Data Source=aigaiosPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DataBaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI;User ID=aigaiosPC\Aigaios;Password=myPassword;)
conn.Open()
```

But I always get an exception when it tries to open:
The given computer with SQL Server couldn't be found: aigaiosPC\SQLEXPRESS

I found the connection string on [connectionsstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/)

---

How can I connect? Do I have to change the SQL Server Settings or the **Norton Firewall**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont know much about windows ce 5.

but the Integrated Security=SSPI  is similar to Integrated Security=true.
this means [the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.integratedsecurity.aspx)

sounds to me like, your user "User ID=aigaiosPC\Aigaios;Password=myPassword" will be ignored.
so you have to give the current Windows Account from your device the rights to access the database.

if still not working i would suggest you to go the following way, to identify where the problem is:

1. try to ping the server from the client to check if they are in the
       same network. if ping fails --> fix general network issues
2. Check if remote access for sqlserver2012 is enabled [Enable Remote
       Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)

another possible problems could be:

- firewall, port 1433, disable firewall for a moment
- use ipadress\SQLEXPRESS instead of pcname\SQLEXPRESS

thats how i would debug it.

Comment: Thanks for your help Koryu. It has helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I did this and now i can connect:
1. On the Start menu, click **Run**. In the Run window type **cmd**, and then click **OK**.
2. In the command prompt window, type **ipconfig** and press enter. Note the **IPv4 address**.
3. Run SQL Server **Configuration Manager**.
4. Go to SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols for SQLEXPRESS.
5. Make sure TCP/IP is **enabled**.
6. Right-click on TCP/IP and select Properties.
7. Verify that, under IP2, the IP Address is set to your IPv4 address.
8. Make sure that, under IPAll, TCP Dynamic Ports is **blank**. (mine was some 5-digit port number.)
9. Make sure that TCP Port is set to **1433** (mine was blank).

Source:
[Enable Remote Connections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)
[Troubleshoot SQL Database Engine](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx)