# Using Entity framework with SQL Server 2012 (local *.mdf database)

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to create a database in an MVC project. Code-First approach. I wrote my models and a `DbContext` database. I am having trouble making the connection to the database. My suspect that the problem is in my connection string but I am not sure. the database I want will consist of two tables, which are defined as follows:

```
public class EmployeeRequest
{
    [Key]
    public int EmployeeRequestId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public int ExtNumber { get; set; }
    public bool isProcessed { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }
}
```

and

```
public class ChangeOrder
{
    [Key]
    public int ChangeOrderId { get; set; }
    public short Operation { get; set; } //0 - Add, 1- delete
    public int TargetExt { get; set; }
    public short Status { get; set; } //0- Pending, 1- Approved, 2- Denied
    public DateTime DtRequested { get; set; }
    public DateTime DtProcessed { get; set; }
    public DateTime DtChangesApplied { get; set; }
    public int EmployeeRequestID { get; set; }
    public virtual EmployeeRequest Request { get; set; }
 }
```

The `DbContext` class is:

```
public class RequestsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EmployeeRequest> EmployeeRequests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }
}
```

Connection string:

```
<add name="RequestsContext" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb);Database=Requests.mdf;Trusted_Connection=True"/>
```

The error I get says that the connection could not be made to the host.

I am nor sure why this is happening. Any Ideas?

Comment: As crazy as this sounds, try changing your Data Source to be `(localdb)\v11.0` instead of just `(localdb)`.

Comment: ok those parameters have fixed something, but now I get an error saying "Cannot attache the file path\to\App_Data\Requests.mdf as database 'Requests.mdf"

Comment: That's an interesting one. Try changing the Database setting from `Requests.mdf` to `Requests` and see if that does something.

Comment: using this connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Database=Requests.mdf" a credential form pops up, with a server field set as (localdb)\v11.0, Database set as Requests.mdf, and it asks me to either use windows authentication or SQL Server authentication. I tried both but neither is working. Nothing changes if I use Requests instead of Requests.mdf

Answer (score 1):

Give the connection string to the DbContext base.

```
public class RequestsContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<EmployeeRequest> EmployeeRequests { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ChangeOrder> ChangeOrders { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

    public RequestsContext ()
    : base("RequestsContext")
    {}

}
```

Comment: This made it stop complaining about credintials, but still no *.mdf file in App_data. What do I need to do to generate that. I already generated two controllers for the models and that went fine this time

Comment: When you use a .mdf the connection string is wrong. Remove .mdf or use the AttachDbFilename property. Check the connection string for database file attaching on: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012

Comment: ill try that once I deal with the routing problem that I just discovered!!

Comment: Yes, I am not sure what solved it exactly but it worked when I did this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012. check out the solution with the most votes. Also you need to enable NETWORK SERVICES from IIS management tool

Comment: Glad it works, but what connection string are you using? without or with .mdf?

Comment: I couldnt get it to work with .mdf, I am using SqlServer Compact for now, Ill figure out how to convert .sdf to .mdf when I move it to production, but at least I have something working now for development. <add name="Requests" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Request.sdf" />

Comment: also make sure you have teh appropriate defaultConnectionfactory <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework"> and <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34485/discussion-between-martijn-van-put-and-user2247823)

Answer (score 1):

Please check the application has access to .mdf file location. If your application resides in "myDocuments" etc type of folders, the application may not have access to it by default.

Comment: I still do not have the *.mdf file, From what I understood I believe that it should generate that for me when everything is good