# Cannot connect remotely to SQL Server instance

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an instance of SQL Server 2012 and when I try to connect with it from other PC through SQL Server Management Studio it's not even visible. I can see all other instances which are placed on other PCs.

I tried everything to fix it:

- disabled firewall
- turned off Anti-Virus
- enabled remote connections to this server
- enabled TCP/IP protocol in SQL Server Manager
- checked if SQL Server and SQL Server Browser is running
- restarted SQL Server and SQL Server Browser a lot of times
- also tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11278115/2717303
- and finally I have reinstalled SQL Server and every component of it

And still I can't see my instance. Does somebody have any other ideas how to fix it?

Here are some screenshots of SQL Server Configuration Manager:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: have you tried pinging the the remote pc or vice versa

Comment: Have you looked at SQL Server Browse Service to make sure the instance is actually present: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx

Comment: What OS are you using, also, can we see a screen shot of Sql Server Configuration Manager

Comment: @bew Yes, I tried, it works well.

Comment: @SelectDistinct Windows 7 64bit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What **server name** you are using ?

You have to open port for it. After opening port your `server name` looks like follow.

**server name** : `IP\SqlExpress, 5012`

Where **5012** is random port.

Comment: How to do this, where should I open this port? As I said before I have disabled firewall.

Comment: see this link http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

Comment: after opening the port don't miss to write it in your server name like I have mention it in my answer

Comment: I did all the things and I can connect with it by writing server name and port as you said, but when I try to find instances through SQL Server Management Studio it is still not visible while the others instances are.

Comment: select @@ServerName in query analyser gives you server\instance.

Comment: Well, I think we misunderstood eachother. I added a screenshot with a window of availibles SQL Server instances in network, and I can't see my instance there (name "CLOUDSQLSERVER").

Comment: You have to add the IP of your remote machine. You can not use the CLOUDSQLSERVER on your local PC. Use like this. IP\CLOUDSQLSERVER,port.

Comment: This list is generated automatically so I cannot manually add any instance of it. Weird thing is that instances that are visible were created on computers with the same SQL SERVER configuration and there was no problem with Ports or anything.

Comment: Will you able to login/connect to sql server by using sql server authentication ?

Comment: What Server name you are using ?

Comment: when I connect manually through IP\CLOUDSQLSERVER,1433 I'm able to login with sql server authentication and it works well, but when I want to search network for available instances it's not showing up.

Comment: You can't get that instance.

Comment: So any idea why I can get other instances?

Comment: Because sql server find these instance on local PC. CLOUDSQLSERVER  is the sql server instance which is on server/Machine.

Comment: Not really, these instances are not on local PC, they are also on different servers.

Comment: Ok do one thing. Run this query SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'Server Name'. check what CLOUDSQLSERVER is there or not

Comment: It returns 'BONIO\CLOUDSQLSERVER' so it's my computerName\instanceName

Comment: Ok I've finally fixed it. Problem was with Workgroup settings, you have to enable streaming media in workgroup settings and then SQL Server Management Studio can easily find it.

Comment: Oh good. Finally you did it