# Unable to connect To the SQL server using the given connection String (using C# windows Application)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, windows-server-2008

I am helping my friend in his college final year project, Its an C# application in a client machine and it uses SQL server in the windows server 2008 environment.

VM ware environment:

---

3 clients(windows 7) and 1 SQL database (in windows 2008)

The connection between he server and the client is working, the port 1433 for SQL is open and its listening.

When I try to run the program am getting the following error.

[image: Error Message when i run the SQL code in the application on button-click]

This is the connection string which am using.

> cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.2,1433;Initial
>   Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");

And i have also tried to refer this website for connection strings, but i don't know how it works.

http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008

> Data Source=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN; Initial
>   Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

I am getting an error. Tried to give a simple username and password in the SQL server and tried it, still the same issue. please check the image. The Username and password which i used is the System login(windows authentication)

[image: Error message when i use the username and password]

I just want to access the SQL server in the Windows 2008 machine.

Where should i check the credentials for this connection string ?

Thank you soo much for reading this patiently.

Comment: take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/  .....it's a fairly common problem with **tons** of *not only Google results* but also SO results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing the port from your connection string (1433 is the default SQL port):

```
cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.2;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=True");
```

For a connection using sql authentication (which would eliminate trust issues between machines) use the following (replacing xxxx and yyyy  with the appropriate user name and password):

```
cn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=192.168.1.2;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=False; User=xxxx; Password=yyyy");
```

Comment: Thannkzz Plymouth223, i did it successfully :), well good news is this project got 1st Grade.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to [Connectionstrings.com](http://Connectionstrings.com) to get more information on connection strings and its usages.

Comment: Thannkzz Rajesh, i did it successfully :), well good news is this project got 1st Grade.