# godaddy.com db connect to sql server studio management Error 53

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, asp.net-4.0

I want attach my local MS SQL db to www.godaddy.in server can anyone suggest me how i can attach my db. Or how i can connect my sql server 2008 studio management to www.godaddy.in server. when i'm trying to connect my sql server studio management to www.godaddy.in server it's not connect showing Error

(Provider: Named Pipes Provider, error:40, and microsoft sql server error 53)

[image]

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/24/sql-server-fix-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-fix-connection-problems-of-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2102.how-to-troubleshoot-connecting-to-the-sql-server-database-engine.aspx

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012

**Short Answer**

- Check Firewall
- Check Service is Running
- Check TCP/IP is Enabled
- Check SQL Server Properties "Allow Remote Connections"

Then Run these if Those Do not Resolve

- Right-click on TCP/IP and select Properties.
- Verify that, under IP2, the IP Address is set to the computer's IP address on the local subnet.
- Scroll down to IPAll.
- Make sure that TCP Dynamic Ports is blank.
- Make sure that TCP Port is set to 1433.
- If you have a named instance then you must have the SQL Server Browser Service enabled
- The browser service runs on port UDP 1434 and this must be allowed through your firewall

Hail Mary Pass if this is Still not Resolved

- Go to the client machine, and run cliconfg.exe If named pipes is listed first, demote it, and promote TCP/IP.
- check if the firewall is blocking the named pipes port, which usually is 445