# How to connect to SQL Server 2000 from .net 4

Tags: sql-server, .net-4.0

Here's my connection string...

```
Data Source=MYMACHINE\SERVER2000; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; User Id=sa; Password=p;
```

Here's the error....

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
>   Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
>   Specified)

I can connect fine with Enterprise Manager. Also I have upgraded the SQL Server to Serivce Pack 4.

Any ideas what the issue might be?

Comment: Try with the old-style connection string: In your case it would be something like this: `server=MYMACHINE\SERVER2000; database=MyDatabase; uid=sa; pwd=p;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest testing your connection string using a .UDL file. I've answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300623/error-the-server-was-not-found-or-was-not-accessible-when-trying-to-connect/20300701#20300701). After creating your connection, you can rename the extension of the file to .txt, open it and then copy and paste the working connection string in.

Comment: Yes that worked although I had to remove the 'Provider' attribute from the string and instead update the 'providerName' on the XML element to be 'System.Data.OleDb'. It connects with ADO.net. But Code First won't connect.

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionString=@"Data Source=MYMACHINE\SERVER2000; Initial Catalog=MyDatabase; User Id=sa; Password=p;";
SqlConnection connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString);
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select * From Table",connection);
SqlDataReader reader= command.ExecuteReader();

GridView1.DataSource=reader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Use this.... this may help you?