# How should be connection string for connection with SQL Server in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, database, web-hosting

I have developed a website in asp.net and upload onto a server. But I unable to connect to my SQL Server database (on `localhost`, I am able to run but not on the server)

I am using following code.

```
con = new SqlConnection("server=**********,****\\sqlexpress;Database=******;User ID=******;Password=*********");
con.Open();
```

but I'm unable to open the connection.

I am getting this error related to `web.config`:

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Notes: The current error page you are seeing can be replaced by a custom error page by modifying the `defaultRedirect` attribute of the application's `<customErrors>` configuration tag to point to a custom error page URL.

```
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="mycustompage.htm"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

So please help me how can resolve it

Comment: Where is the database in server machine or somewhere else ?

Comment: database is in server machine

Comment: I think there is problem in instance name. You can use (local) as sever or use lan IP of that machine.

Comment: I would guess that the **server**'s database instance probably isn't called `.\SQLEXPRESS`. Most likely, it's either a default instance without a name, so try `.` or `(local)` or `ServerName` as your server name, or then it's some other instance name that you should know or inquire about with the server's hosting service.

Comment: Yes, I agree, the server name is not correct. Please kindly check it again. If you use hosting provider, please ask them about the correct connection string.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;

Check the instance name of the remote server. Check if you can connect in sql management studio and use the same credentials in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I've answered two similar questions on SO, first try creating a .UDL file and test your connection from there. You can then copy and paste the connection string. You may need to remove the `Provider` property though.

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20470490/how-to-connect-to-sql-server-2000-from-net-4/20470773#20470773) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300623/error-the-server-was-not-found-or-was-not-accessible-when-trying-to-connect/20300701#20300701) for a full description.