# How to access SQL Server 2012 Express remotely

Tags: sql-server-express, sql-server-2012-express, remote-connection

I am using SQL Server 2012 Express and I have enabled remote connections plus also have followed the steps give in the [LINK](http://www.linglom.com/it-support/enable-remote-connection-on-sql-server-2008-express/)

However I am unable to access the server remotely and what server name should be specified the public ip address?

[image]

Comment: When you say "remote" do you mean over the internet or from another machine on the same network?

Comment: Well you blurred out the name you are trying to connect by, but it doesn't look long enough to represent either a fully-qualified domain name or an IP address, if the instance name is `\SQLEXPRESS`. Are you sure you're trying to connect to a name you can successfully ping, tracert or telnet to over the Internet?

Comment: @AaronBertrand i am using 41.191.125.29 ip

Comment: And is your Express instance a named instance? Did you try `41.191.125.29\SQLEXPRESS`?

Comment: My sql express name is: INMSAPP01\SQLEXPRESS on the local machine. Yes i tried doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try to access the SQL Server by using SQL Management Studio on a local network.

If that works, then make sure the correct ports have been forwarded on your firewall/router (Default Port 1433), this should be TCP.

To access this over the internet you should then connect using SQL Server Management Studio using your "external" IP Address, you can get this by going to `www.whatismyip.com` from the SQL Server.

However, make sure you disable and do not use the `sa` account if this is on the internet and to be honest I would strongly advise against exposing a SQL Server on the internet.

Other means are more secure such as open up RDP and Remote Desktop to a machine on your network and then connect to SQL Server from there. Or worst case, RDP straight onto the SQL Server.

Comment: hi what do u mean you can get this by going to www.whatismyip.com from the SQL Server?

Comment: That will give you your internet's external IP address. That is was you should connect to in SQL Management Studio

Comment: So you need to try using this address: myexternalip\SQLEXPRESS

Comment: Have you actually forwarded port 1433 on your router to the SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

You may also find post: "Enable remote connections for SQL Server Express 2012"  helpful. This shows that Express is far from 'express' and takes a bit of know how to get external connections, even from the same network..
[Enable remote connections for SQL Server Express 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)