# How to connect other pc to database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

How to connect other pc to database SQL server 2008? I created C# Login form in my PC and it works properly, but when I try to my another PC in LAN I can't login is gives an error "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server". I tried to find a solution but no luck.

This is my sqlconnection object:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=jason-PC\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog=db_Lan; User Id=wew; Password=password;");
```

I have also enabled `TCP/IP` and remote.

I hope you can help me because I am a beginner.

Comment: You have to enable remote access to SQL Server see: [7 things to check to resolve  “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server…](http://www.sswug.org/articlesection/default.aspx?TargetID=44331)

Comment: try to handle the firewall of that machine. If you have permissions then disable firewall for few minutes and try to reconnect. If it works then you have to add an exception/rule in firewall. remember to enable firewall again.

Comment: SQL Server Express does not enable remote connections by default. Also be sure necessary ports are open in your firewall

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stated earlier - you need to enable remote connections. SQL Server Express does not enable this by default. you also need to enable your firewall access to SQL Server for remote access.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlexpress/archive/2005/05/05/415084.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx

[Enable remote connections for SQL Server Express 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)

Comment: Do I need to change my connection string?

Comment: Also make sure you have you sql server port open on the firewall. Usually port 1433.

Comment: no. :) just make sure it can resolve the computer name or use the IP Address instead. but you DO need to enable remote connections on the server that hosts SQL Server Express