# SQL Server : can't login with Windows Authentication

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, sql-server-express

We bought a virtual dedicated server. Then I installed SQL Server Express on it. And then I installed SQL Server Management Studio to run this on windows server 2008. But I cannot connect the database. It gives me a "cannot connect error". How can I connect to vds' database?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Enable remote connections for SQL Server Express 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)

Comment: See this [other SO question (and its answers!)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012) on how to enable remote connections to SQL Server Express (which are **off** by default)

Comment: Are you sure you want to logon with Windows Authentication? Are you a logged on user of a domain on the remote system? Try the "SQL Server Authentication" option instead

Comment: I tried SQL Server Authentication but cannot login . I don't want to login with windows authentication. But i cannot login with anyone. @AlexK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed sql server 2008 R2 management studio on my computer. Then i tried to connect database with remote connection. I opened my firewall port 1433. And it is working.