# Classic ASP connecttion string to SQL Express

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have ASP pages that connect to SQL Server (10.50.1400) with the connection string

```
conn.Open ("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=svr;UID=ui;PWD=pw;DATABASE=db");
```

but recently was installed an EXPRESS instance and my pages ASP start don't connect to SQL Server (10.50.4000) database. I changed my connection string to

```
conn.Open ("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=svr\EXPRESS;UID=ui;PWD=pw;DATABASE=db");
```

but still don't work. Also (googling) I changed to

```
conn.Open ("Provider=SQLOLEDB;SERVER=svr;UID=ui;PWD=pw;DATABASE=db");
```

but the same. The error that "SQL Server don't exist or connection refused".

Any help, please. Thanks!

Comment: Are you accessing it from different machine? if so then you need to configure TCP/IP configuration for the sql express instance.

Comment: all the machines, server and desktops, are in the same domain and use DHCP. The unique change was the SQL to SQL EXPRESS

Comment: Even though it is the new instance of the sql server you need to configure TCP/IP for this express instance.

Comment: can check the following link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012

Comment: Hum! Ok. I will send this clue to SQL server administrator to study. I hope this help. Thanks.