# Can't conect to a SQL Server Express from a remote computer

Tags: sql-server, connection, remote-access

i need to establish a conecction to a SQL Server Express from remotes pcs. But i can do it, only can establish it from the pc where is the SQL. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have to enable remote SQL connection -->
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Integrated Security (Windows Authentication) and a local user account (from the PC with SQL installed), such account can only be authenticated on that PC.

For database account (SQL Server Authentication) you'll need to create a database login and enable Mixed authentication (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188670.aspx)