# Error connecting local SQL via Powershell from vm

Tags: sql-server, powershell, networking, hyper-v

Some insight, closed lab environment, Windows Server 2012 (host) with 2 VM's Windows 8.1 (guests) on INTERNAL Virtual Switch. Host is set as default gateway with ip 1, VMs accordingly 2 and 3. All the entities can see each other on the network, that means I can ping, tracert or share files through file sharing, moreover I can  even invoke-command from every place to another.

The deal is that I've got a SQL Server Express instance (`SQLEXPRESS`) installed on host but I can't connect to it in Powershell from vm's using following piece of code:

```
$sql_Server = "HOST\SQLEXPRESS"
$sql_User = "User"
$sql_Password = "Password"
$sql_Database = "Database"
$sql_Connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sql_Connection.ConnectionString = "Server=$sql_Server; Uid=$sql_User; Pwd=$sql_Password; Database=$sql_Database"
$sql_Connection.Open()
```

All I've got is following error:

> Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)"

Following your questions:

- Firewall if off on all of them,
- Tcp port 1433 enabled,
- above piece of code works from host

I know not much about networks so I guessing that I'm missing something in this puzzle

Comment: SQL Server **Express** by default doesn't allow **remote connections** - those have to be explicitly allowed

Comment: This thread may help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012

Comment: @andyb thanks, it was not exacly the answer but it got me to it! I had to run sql browser.

Answer (score 0):

I had to run SQL Browser service to be able to query server from VM.