# Visual Studio 2010 Shell cannot connect to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2012

I installed VS2013, VS2010 Shell (for the BI-Tools) and SQL Server 2012 on Windows 8.1 Pro. I configured the SQL Server and attached the `AdventureWork2012` database successfully.

I created datasource > dataview > cube from the db above.

However, I got an error saying

> "The project could not be deployed to the 'XX\DBT2' server because of
>   the following connectivity problems: A connection cannot be made to
>   redirector. Ensure that 'SQL Browser' service is running. TO verify or
>   update the name of the target server..."

I've checked the SQL Server and SQL Server Browser and both are running. (checked from SQL Server Configuration Manger)

I also checked the db connection I set up on the VB project. It said Test connection succeeded.

I think I missing some user permission thing but not sure which one is it so here is a little more info about the user right. The user I am using is the account that setup with the windows installation. I also followed some other article online that they said added a few more admin right (user, group) will solve this issue which it didn't for this case.

I also go into the SQL Server Management Studio and check the database permission. And the user right as well but I can't seem to find any problem.

Comment: Have you tried connecting using ip and port instead? Something like this: '123.123.123.123, 1433'

Comment: Just tried "192.168.0.XXX:1433\DBT2" and no luck. Same error

Comment: Another follow up. Tried using it to connect to the db though MS SQL Server Management Studio. and it said "The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connections"

Comment: The syntax is `192.168.0.xxx, 1433` Remove `:` and `\DBT2` (this is assuming you are using the default 1433 port.

Comment: Refer to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16923528/193634

Comment: Tried, not working. So this seem to be some of my configuration problem...I followed some of their reply and no luck. But I installed everything from the package list so I dont think I missed anything

Comment: Have you allowed UDP 1434 on the SQL box? Both on firewall and Windows firewall.

Comment: Also, OP might need to check this information first. I see that you are using a named instance "DBT2". If so it is very unlikely that it will be on port 1433. In fact unless OP manually changed the config then it will be on a dynamic port, changing on every SQL service restart.

Hence my suggestion is not using port number in connection string, and fix your SQL Browser problem.