# How to connect SQL Server Express database from another Pc?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Example there are three PC's

```
PC1, PC2 and PC3
```

There is Server PC1 and that have only SQL Server Express Installed.

Can anyone give me the connection string and settings to connect PC1 from PC2 and PC3?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48667/how-to-access-a-sql-server-database-from-other-computer-connected-to-the-same-wo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `PC1`, you must ensure that the SQL Server Express instance allows **remote connections** (see [this other SO question and its answers for details on how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012).

Also, you need to create **logins** on the server instance, and **users** in your database(s). If all those three PC's are members in a Windows network, you can probably create logins based on Windows user accounts - otherwise, you have to use SQL Server specific logins.

Then, on PC2 and PC3, you can use something like this:

```
server=PC1;database=YourDatabase;User ID=SomeUserID;Password=SomePassword
```

See [ConnectionStirngs.com](http://ConnectionStirngs.com) for a great many more examples and explanations

**Update:**

If I understand correctly, this is what you want to do:

- have `PC1` be the "server" in your setup - if so, then install SQL Server Express **with tools** (including the Management Studio) on this server. Make a note of **what instance name** you use when installing SQL Server Express! The default is `SQLEXPRESS`, but you can choose anything you like
- make sure the SQL Server Express instance allows **remote connections**
- create the necessary logins on that server instance
- create your database **on that server** (where it belongs - after all, SQL **Server** is a **server-based** solution)
- create the necessary users in that database for your logins

With this setup, you should easily be able to connect from `PC2` and `PC3` to your SQL Server database on `PC1`

Comment: ID=SomeUserID;Password=SomePassword is the computer username and Password or Sql User paswd?

Comment: @parth: those are the credentials for the **SQL Server** instance you're connecting to

Comment: SqlConnection Connection = new SqlConnection(@"server=PC1;database=YourDatabase;User ID=PC1UserId;Password=PC1Password") Is it like that..?

Comment: it not work Server name is Pc name or Sql Instance Nameof that Pc or What?

Comment: @parth: the default instance name of a SQL Server Express is `SQLEXPRESS` - so try `server=pc1\SQLEXPRESS` in your connection string. But that's just the default - maybe you or whoever installed this SQL Server Express changed it .... then you need to use the appropriate instance name

Comment: It's not work then also i have to place database in specific place or wherever it place they automatically detect.

Comment: @parth: the database just has to be **attached** to the server - not referenced as a "free-floating" `.mdf` file ....

Comment: But i dont want to buy Management Studio that's whay i am doing with SqlExpress after installing the management Studion on PC1 then its wok that i know.

Comment: hope you Understand I only want SqlExpress on Server and Connect From all Pcs to Server (PC1) Where the Databse is actually.

Comment: @parth: Management Studio is a ***FREE*** download for SQL Server Express..... you don't need to **buy** anything ....

Comment: Ok then i am Using SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU (Sql Express with Tools ) that is Free I think..thanks.

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=22973 It's Free?

Comment: @parth: ***Y-E-S*** SQL Server **Express** (all versions of it) is entitrely, totally, utterly ***F-R-E-E*** - even for commercial use

Comment: thanks a lot..for your support..