# Enable remote connections for SQL Server 2014 Express

Tags: sql-server-2014-express, remote-connection

I have a SQL Server 2014 Express installed and I want to allow remote connections. I have read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012), but I can't find the configuration manager installed on the system.

So my question: where can this configuration be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fire up SQL Server Management Studio, and in the Object Explorer, right-click on the server node, choose `Properties`.

You should get a dialog something like this (it might look a little bit different in Express, but basically, that's what you should get):

[image]

Tick the checkbox `Allow remote connections to this server`