# I moved the database to a remote computer

Tags: entity-framework, connection

This is my connection string in local db,

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="liderdatabaseEntities" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=C:\Users\Bertan\Documents\liderdatabase.mdf;integrated security=True;connect timeout=30;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I moved the database to a remote computer (192.168.1.100)
What should be the new connectionstring, thank you.

Comment: Does that other computer also have SQL Server Express `LocalDB` installed?

Comment: sql express installed to remote computer and added sa user, password

Comment: **(1)** ensure that the SQL Server Express on that other computer allows **remote connections** (off by default), and **(2)** adapt your connection string accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First things is to ensure that this other computer's SQL Server Express instance allows **remote connections** - those are **OFF** by default. 
[See my answer to this other SO question as to how to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34657877/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-2014-express/34658921#34658921).

Then, you need to adapt the connection string - and I'd **strongly recommend** putting the database **on the server** (attach the `.mdf` file to the SQL Server Express instance) instead of fiddling around with free-floating `.mdf` files. And also: I'd again **strongly recommend** never ever to use the `sa` user - create a separate login/user for your application!

Basically, you need to change the `provbider connection string` inside your connection string from

```
provider connection string=&quot;
    data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
    attachdbfilename=C:\Users\Bertan\Documents\liderdatabase.mdf;
    integrated security=True;
    connect timeout=30;
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
    App=EntityFramework&quot;
```

to something like

```
provider connection string=&quot;
    data source=192.168.1.100\SQLEXPRESS;
    database=liderdatabase;
    user id=someuser;
    password=password;
    connect timeout=30;
    MultipleActiveResultSets=True;
    App=EntityFramework&quot;
```