# org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

i am developing an application with spring hibernate in that if i am using database like 199.892.2.345 ,i am able to connect to that database and do CURD operation,but if i change that to cloud database like vinayaka.cloudapp.net,111 in spring config i get below errors ,below is the spring config file i am using,

Spring.config.xml

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"  
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"  
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd  
  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd">  

 <context:component-scan base-package="com.beingjavaguys.controller" />  
 <mvc:annotation-driven />  

 <bean id="dataSource"  
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />  
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://vinayaka.cloudapp.net,111\sqlexpress;database=SampleDatabase" />  
  <property name="username" value="user" />  
  <property name="password" value="pass" /> 

 </bean>  


 <bean id="sessionFactory"  
 class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">  
 <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />  
 <property name="annotatedClasses">  
 <list>  
   <value>com.beingjavaguys.model.Employee</value>   

   </list>  
  </property>  
  <property name="hibernateProperties">  
   <props>  

    <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect</prop>  
    <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>  
   </props>  
  </property>  
 </bean>
```

error

```
  org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:132)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.connection(StatementPreparerImpl.java:63)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:162)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:160)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.prepareQueryStatement(Loader.java:1884)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1861)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:1838)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:909)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2553)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2539)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2369)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2364)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:353)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1873)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:311)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:141)
    at com.beingjavaguys.dao.DataDaoImpl.getEntityById(DataDaoImpl.java:54)
    at com.beingjavaguys.services.DataServicesImpl.getEntityById(DataServicesImpl.java:24)
    at com.beingjavaguys.controller.RestController.getEmployee(RestController.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:215)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:689)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:436)
    at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:177)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection to the host vinayaka.cloudapp.net,111, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: vinayaka.cloudapp.net,111". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:190)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getInstancePort(SQLServerConnection.java:3589)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.primaryPermissionCheck(SQLServerConnection.java:1225)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:972)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:827)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1012)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:155)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 62 more
```

Comment: Shouldn't DataSource url be `jdbc:sqlserver://vinayaka.cloudapp.net:111/sqlexpress`?

Comment: @Armaiti  i was using jdbc:sqlserver://vinayaka.cloudapp.net:111\sqlexpress ,now i changed to jdbc:sqlserver://vinayaka.cloudapp.net:111/sqlexpress,now i get this error The TCP/IP connection to the host vinayaka.cloudapp.net,111/sqlexpress, port 1433 has failed. Error: "null. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

Comment: In the error message I still see `vinayaka.cloudapp.net,111/sqlexpress` instead of `vinayaka.cloudapp.net:111/sqlexpress`. Make sure the port 111 is correct, it doesn't seem to be right.

Comment: @Armaiti if i change i get error saying com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The port number 111/sqlexpress is not valid.i am able to connect database with same credential in mssql server with server name:vinayaka.cloudapp.net,111/sqlexpress and user:user ,password:pass but why i am not able to connect through application?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Enable remote connections for SQL Server Express 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)

Answer (score 1):

You have to enable the TCP/IP from the SQL server Configuration Manager and define any port too to send/receive connections. For more information you can refer the following link :-

http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-1433.aspx

Comment: the problem here is i am able to connect to local database ,but for azure sql i am not able to connect,should i change any configuration so that it could connect to azure sql?

Comment: @dafodil did you find a solution?

Comment: @Eddy No , but you may refer  Peter Pan - MSFT answer ,if you are creating database in azure http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197014/not-able-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database-server-using-spring?noredirect=1#comment58310845_35197014  .But this was not what i was looking for.