# Not able to connect to Azure SQL Database server using spring

Tags: java, spring, azure, azure-sql-database

I am able to connect to database which is having ip address,but if 
i have my database created in Azure SQL Database server in that i am not able to connect using spring configuration Java web application.It shows me error  saying

The connection to the host vinayaka.cloudapp.net,555, named instance sqlexpress failed. Error: "java.net.UnknownHostException: vinayaka.cloudapp.net,555". Verify the server and instance names and check that no firewall is blocking UDP traffic to port 1434.  For SQL Server 2005 or later, verify that the SQL Server Browser Service is running on the host.

spring-config.xml

```
<bean id="dataSource"  
  class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"> 
  <property name="driverClassName" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />  
  <property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://vinayaka.cloudapp.net,555\sqlexpress;database=Sample" />  
  <property name="username" value="user" />  
  <property name="password" value="pass" />    
 </bean>
```

Note:

1) I am able to open and work on that server in SQL Server Management Studio.

2) If I am able to open in SQL Server Management Studio, it means my machine IP address is allowed by firewall.

3) I can connect to database created in Azure SQL Database.

Please give suggestion on this.

Comment: Can you provide the JDBC driver version number? Have you been able to successfully connect when using the following url?: `jdbc:sqlserver://SERVERNAME.database.windows.net:1433;database=spring-boot-intr‌​o;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=false;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.wind‌​ows.net;loginTimeout=30;`

Answer (score 1):

The connection string of Azure SQL Database for JDBC is like `jdbc:sqlserver://<hostname>.database.windows.net:1433;database=<dbname>;user=<user>@<hostname>;password={your_password_here};encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30;`.

You can check the connection string of your Azure SQL Database on Azure old portal or new portal, please see the pictures below.

**Pic 1. Check the Connection String for JDBC on Azure old portal**
[image]

**Pic 2. Check the Connection String for JDBC on Azure new portal**
[image]

Comment: i have mentioned in note of that  "I can connect to database created in sql database in Azure" .In this there will be other tab called server along with next to sql database tab.in that i have my server inside that i have a database.Yes to this server i am not able to connect.

Comment: @dafodil Hi, I think there are two cases. 1. You need to use the sqlserver jdbc driver version later than 4.0. 2. You need allow the client ip in the firewall rules, operate at the `Manage allowed IP addresses`.

Answer (score 0):

Is `555` the port, that is exposed by the database for connection?
Shouldn't the connection string look like this?

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:sqlserver://vinayaka.cloudapp.net:555\sqlexpress;database=Sample" />
```

I have replaced `,` in your code with `:`

Comment: I had also tried with this .it gives me Could not open connection and  The port number 555\sqlexpress is not valid. error

Comment: Is your database port open for the incoming connections in the firewall?

Comment: Yes,the same sql server is being used in other platform(asp.net) to fetch data in same port.Its working fine.If i connect other sql in this port its working fine.The problem is only with "Azure SQL Database server"

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string like "jdbc:sqlserver://{HostName}.database.windows.net;database={databaseName};encrypt=true;hostNameInCertificate=*.database.windows.net;loginTimeout=30".
And use sqljdbc4 jar file. Hope it should work.