# Problems in connecting the sqlserver database in MS Azure from STS through Socksify (Open Text Socks Client)

Tags: java, sql-server, azure, spring-mvc, database-connection

Im trying to connect a SQL Server database in MS Azure from my Spring application in my local machine over a firewall through OpenText socks Client But, I'm getting the error below,

> The TCP/IP connection to the host , port 1433 has failed. Error: "Bad address: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".

I can connect to the same database through SQL Server management studio without any issues through OpenText socks client. But, I'm facing issues when i try to deploy the spring mvc application in tomcat server. Deployment fails saying the stack trace below,

```
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection to the host <host name here>, port 1433 has failed. Error: "Bad address: connect. Verify the connection properties. Make sure that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port. Make sure that TCP connections to the port are not blocked by a firewall.".
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:206)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.ConvertConnectExceptionToSQLServerException(SQLServerException.java:257)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SocketFinder.findSocket(IOBuffer.java:2385)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.open(IOBuffer.java:567)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1955)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1616)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1447)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:788)
      at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1187)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
      at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:153)
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:144)
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:196)
      at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:159)
      at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122)
      at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:386)
      at org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.acquireConnectionIfNeeded(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:84)
      ... 31 more
```

I have tried whitelisting my IP address in Azure but that doesnt worked.
I have also tried adding the STS in socks application list but no luck.

Can some one please guide me to connect the SQLServer in MS Azure through OpenText socks client from my Spring MVC application over a firewall? Or Can you please suggest any other way to achieve this other than OpenText Socks Client?

Comment: See if this similar thread helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35197014/not-able-to-connect-to-azure-sql-database-server-using-spring

Comment: @VKJava What type of SQL Server did you use in Azure? Azure SQL Database or SQL Server installed on Azure Windows VM?

Comment: @ Peter Pan, I use SQL server installed on Azure Windows VM

Comment: @VKJava So have you added an inbound rule into NSG to allow TCP connection in port 1433, and added the same inbound rule into Windows firewall for port 1433?

Comment: @Peter Pan, Yes. As an additional note, I can successfully connect the database using SSMS from my machine with open text socks client. But, only when I try to connect it through my spring application, it doesn't work.