# SQL Server 2014- can't connect to local db - can not find server

Tags: sql-server-2014-express

I just installed SQL Server 2014 Management Studio and when I tried to connect to my local db server, I get this message:

[image]

What could be the problem, and what can I do to solve it?

Comment: Did you try adding ".\" (period backslash) before your database name? (meaning that name on the local computer)

Comment: By default, SQL Server **Express** is installed as a `SQLEXPRESS` instance, so you need to use `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` as your server name (or `BADASSIC\SQLEXPRESS`). Or did you by any chance install **only** the Management Studio? Then you **don't have** an actual SQL Server engine instance at all - you need to install the **core engine** plus the Management Studio (the Mgmt Studio is **ONLY** the management GUI - no database engine!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put correct instance name and ensure that in Services, SQL server service in running.
If it's not running then select appropriate service and start.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the instance name is correct?
You can open SQL Server Configuration to get the correct instance name.

If SQL is installed on another server then you have to allow remote connection from SQL Configuration Manager

Answer (score 0):

As answer above says, you probably got your instance name wrong
A thing you could do is next

Select like on image below

[image: Let SQL find your local server]

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you type the IP address, this is another option to try connect the MS SQL Server, the other thing is that you can review if your Server accept open remote connection.

Here a link for help you:

[Enable remote connections for SQL Server Express 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)