# Set up common database server for vb.net application

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, database-connection, connection-string, vb.net-2010

I have developed a school management software in vb.net. I used in-built database management program of Visual Studio. At first my client requirement was single handed use (i.e. the SW works on only one computer), now suddenly when the software if complete and submitted to client they said to me that work load is very much and they want that multiple user should use the software.

Now I have problem that how do I use my database file (i.e. `.mdf`) in such a way that multiple users can connect to it with different computer **"LOCALLY VIA LAN"**.

Actually I have done some research and I understood very little which is that I can use SQL Server Express as a server on one machine, import my existing DB file into SQL Server Express, and make some changes in my connection string in VB.net so that it connect to the specified DB.

Can someone please help me with my problem or give me some link to which I can refer.

Thanks.

Comment: You have the basic ideas right. 1 - install your database server. 2 - move your current database to the new database server. 3 - connect to it with a new connection string. What is your specific programming issue?

Comment: yes i have basic knowledge. I have don't have any programming issue right now as everything is working fine but **ON A SINGLE COMPUTER.**
I want my DB to have access from multiple computer in a room so that multiple user can work on my software without having any problem.

Comment: This site is for programming issues. You might try reasking your question on the database site, or super user. http://dba.stackexchange.com/  http://superuser.com/

Comment: so sorry. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the point of using SQL *Server*: it's a *server*, not just a file sitting on a computer somewhere.  You have to configure your database *server* to let other machines connect to it, and you'll be fine.  There's a `SQL Server Configuration Manager` tool included with your installation.  Have a look at a question about configuring remote access (e.g., first search result to come up when you search for it, which is [enable remote connections for sql server express](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012).

Other than that, you'll have to configure your connection string information in the application to connect to the particular machine which is hosting your database - e.g., rather than connecting to `(local)` or `.` or something, you'd need to connect to `MyServerMachineName` or whatever.

Comment: thanks for such information.
Actually i was getting confused about it. I will try to configure machine and let you know.