# Access SQL Server Express database from a Mac?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I'm developing an Azure Functions application using Visual Studio on a Mac.

My application is designed to use a Microsoft SQL server database when it goes to production. The production DB is hosted in Azure, so this isn't an issue.

For development, I was given a backup copy of the database. I got the backup running by installing it on a SQL Server Express database on a nearby Windows computer in my office. I can see that the DB is working if I connect to it using SQL Server Management Studio on that computer. However, I have so far not been able to connect to it from my Mac, which is were I plan to do most of my development.

I spent a lot of time digging around on the Windows computer looking for TCP port settings, firewall settings, etc. but could find nothing. How is this done?

Thanks,
Frank

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11278114/61305

Comment: I'm having trouble running the "SQL Configuration Manager". It says I don't have access to the SQL Server.

Comment: You should be able to connect to that instance using Azure Data Studio, https://cloudblogs.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2018/09/25/azure-data-studio-for-sql-server/ and if connection fails, it should tell what might be the causes.

Comment: I really think I did everything right, I have the SQL server listening on port 1433, I have the firewall open, I created a SQL Server account to log into... but on the client side all I get is messages saying it failed to connect.

Comment: I had to start the SQL Server Browser service. That fixed it.