# SQL Server Configuration 32 and 64 Bit Client TCP/IP Configuration without Browser

Tags: sql-server

I'm working through configuring SQL Server express (2017) to listen directly on TCP/IP ports per the other conversations without the browser.

[Enable remote connections for SQL Server Express 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)

With there being a 32 Bit and 64 Bit "Native Client" (both asking for TCP/IP), as well as a 32 Bit and 64 Bit SQL Server Network Configuration (only the later having any information about TCP/IP addresses and ports),

Can all 3 (of the 4 options sets? Why is the one omitted) be set to the same listening TCP/IP port or does this create a clash requiring a segmentation.

[image: 32 Bit Native Client Configuration]
[image: 64 Bit Native Client Configuration]
[image: 64 Bit Network Configuration]
[image: 32 Bit Network Configuration]

Comment: Why are you trying to set a named instance to listen on port 1433? Just install a default instance in this case!

Comment: It was the default install. I could have missed something in the installation. I want to remove the complexity. Is this not possible after installation? I can uninstall and reinstall without a name then set to listen to 1433?

Comment: Yes, you must install a new default instance. It will listen on port 1433.