# SQL Server Management Studio problem with connect

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've got problem with connecting SQL Server by SQL Server Management Studio. I installed the latest version. I want to connect by windows authentication. I tried server name like:

> computer_name\SQLEXPRESS
>
> localhost\SQLEXPRESS
>
> 127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS

But it still doesn't work. I'll be glad for any help with this.

error message:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
> Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Comment: please provide an error message

Comment: Other than the suggested error message, it'd also help if you let us know what you did during installation, and subsequent configuration. Based on your attempted connections, it seems to installed SQL Server Express Edition. Can you confirm? Where did you install it? Did you change any options? Can you confirm it's shown in your list of Services?

Comment: error message: 


A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)


I didn't change anything during installation I installed in default settings.
I installed SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) from MS site.

Comment: Do you try [this steps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11278114/enable-remote-connections-for-sql-server-express-2012)?

Comment: You are using SSMS to connect to a local SQL Server instance. Did you install one? SSMS is only a client tool. It sounds like you installed SSMS but you didn't actually install SQL Server.

Comment: I suggest you start with [this troubleshooting article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4009936/solving-connectivity-errors-to-sql-server).

Comment: I agree with Nick's comment based on your feedback.If you haven't actually installed SQL Express, then you only have the client tools. That does not include a local installation of the actual database engine.